# Swift Error: Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands

Tags: swift

There obviously has to be a way to AND or OR multiple booleans.

I'm getting this error trying to write a function like this...

```
func isLocationWithinView(location: CGPoint, view: UIView) {
    //        return (location.x >= CGRectGetMinX(view.frame)) && (location.x <= CGRectGetMaxX(view.frame)) && (location.y >= CGRectGetMinY(view.frame)) && (location.y <= CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame))
    var a = true
    var b = false
    return a && b // Error: Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands
}
```

What's the solution to this?

Comment: You're missing return type `... -> Bool` in your functions signature. (The error is somewhat misleading: but without return type specified, function expects return type `()` (empty tuple), whereas you return a boolean).

Answer (score 52):

The error is misleading: the core is that you're missing return type `... -> Bool` in your function signature, hence attempting to *assign a boolean value to the empty tuple type `()`* (with no explicit return type, the function expects returns to be of empty tuple type `()`).

You can reproduce this misleading error for any attempt to assign a boolean value to a non-boolean type, where the boolean value is a result of a logical AND/OR expression being performed in the same expression as the invalid assignment:

```
var a : () = (true && false)    /* same error */
var b : Int = (true && false)   /* same error */
var c : () = (true || false)    /* same error (for binary op. '||') */
```

Whereas if you wrap your AND/OR operations in a closure or simply assign them to an intermediate boolean variable, you loose the obfuscated error message and is presented with the actual error.

```
var d : () = { _ -> Bool in return (true && false) }()
    /* Cannot convert call result type 'Bool' to expected type '()' */
var e = true && false
var f : () = e
    /* Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected type '()' */
```

---

Now *as to why* you're given this misleading error. Both logical operators `&&` and `||` are implemented with a conditional evaluation of their right hand side expressions (`rhs`), so that the `rhs` can be lazily evaluated only in case the left hand side (`lhs`) evaluates to `true`/`false` for `&&`/`||` operators, respectively.

```
/* e.g. the AND '&&' logical binary infix operator */
func &&(lhs: BooleanType, @autoclosure rhs: () -> BooleanType) -> Bool {
    return lhs.boolValue ? rhs().boolValue : false
}
```

Since the `lhs` itself is invalid for the assignment that follows, possibly the lazy closure `rhs` throws an error incurred by the "external" invalid assignment from `Bool` type to `()`, but the error thrown (*"Binary op '`&&`' cannot be applied ..."*) is not the actual source of the failure of `&&` call.

To verify, we can implement our own non-lazy AND operator, say `&&&`, and, as expected, we don't receive the same obfuscate error:

```
infix operator &&& {
    associativity right
    precedence 120
}
func &&&(lhs: BooleanType, rhs: BooleanType) -> Bool {
    return lhs.boolValue ? rhs.boolValue : false
}
var g : () = false &&& true
/* Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected type '()' */
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted. This error message is misleading in `Swift 2`, hopefully it will be fixed in future version, like the misleading block related errors previously.

Comment: Still the same in Swift 3

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer has some really interesting points, in this particular case, adding a return type to your function solves it.

```
func isLocationWithinView(location: CGPoint, view: UIView) -> Bool {
    let a = true
    let b = false
    return a && b // Error: Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands
}
```

This would return `true` if `a` were true, and if not, it would look to `b` (lazy evaluation).

Comment: Wouldn't this return true if BOTH a and b are true ? Am I missing something

Comment: Yes it requires both to be true. I’ll have to edit this post or delete