# Comparing two Ints

Tags: swift, swift3

I am searching through a linked list for a specific Int value, but am receiving the error "Binary operator != cannot be applied to two 'Int' operands.

My code:

```
//node.data is an Int
//someInt is an Int

if node.data != someInt {...}
```

I assumed I could compare the `Int` values since `Int` conforms to `Equatable`. Is there a better way to do this?

Full code:

```
class Node<Int> {
    var data: Int
    var next: Node? = nil

    init(data: Int) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class LinkedList<Int> {
    var head: Node<Int>?
    func find(someInt: Int) {
        var partitioningNode = head

        //find node
        guard var node = head else {
            print("empy linked list")
            return
        }
        if node.data != someInt {
            partitioningNode = node
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's odd... that should be totally fine

Comment: As always, a [mcve] would be most helpful.

Comment: Make sure, that they really are Ints. They may be optionals and then they would need ! or ? operator.

Comment: Most likely another error that is obscured by the error message you're given. Construct an actually verifiable example, and you are likely to solve the issue by yourself (as constructing such examples tend to need refactoring the actual implementation). Related: [Swift Error: Binary operator '&&' cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967285/swift-error-binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-two-bool-operands/34967593#34967593)

Comment: I vote that we close this question (brings no value; confusing as its non-verifiable without a MCVE, and already sorted out by OP).

Answer (score 1):

In the vast majority of cases, errors like "Binary operator ... cannot be applied to two 'X' operands," when it absolutely *can* be applied to those types, is just a bug in the diagnostic message generator. You likely have some other type error in the area. Without any context (and we need context), I'd make sure that you've remembered to return something from the encoding function. Sometimes what this means is "I wanted to find a `!=` that would return something like `Float` rather than `Bool` in this context and I couldn't find that, so I complained about the `Int` instead."

But without an MCVE, there's no way to debug it further. You have a type error somewhere nearby.

Comment: Thanks Rob, the type error was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue... Initially my LinkedList and LinkedListNode classes defined a generic `<T>`. While refactoring, I noticed the generic was no longer needed and the data in the nodes only needed to be a single Int, so I incorrectly replaced `<T>` with `<Int>`, thus causing the error when trying to compare two "Ints"

Comment: You can still use generic type of implementing Equatable protocol: 

class Node<T: Equatable> {
    var data: T
    var next: Node<T>? = nil

    init(data: T) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class LinkedList<T: Equatable> {
    var head: Node<T>?

    func find(value: T) -> Node<T>? {

        var partitioningNode = head
        while partitioningNode != nil {
            if let node = partitioningNode, node.data == value {
                return node
            }
            partitioningNode = partitioningNode?.next
        }

        return nil

    }
}